# Infinite redirects after changing the permalink of a page

Tags: permalinks, redirect

I changed the permalink of a page in the WordPress site. It caused to infinitely redirect between the new and old permalink.
To test the scenario I changed the permalink several times and now it has began to redirect all among those URLs.
What may be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem after changing the URL of a page. I found that issue occurred due to a plugin "Yoast SEO". That plugin keeps old URLs and new URLs.If a page redirects unexpectedly or causes a redirect loop only when your plugin is active, this means a redirect has been added to your plugin. To solve this go to the redirects section under SEO plugin and delete the relevant redirect record.

For more details, you can refer here.
https://kb.yoast.com/kb/page-redirects-unexpectedly/